# Open New Window Signal in ActiveQt

Tags: c++, qt, activeqt

How can i get the signal to open the link in new tab.
I am using QTabWidget and i do not want to open it in IE browser. I want to catch the signal in ActiveQt and open the new tab in QTabWidget.

Can you please give me signal handler in ActiveQt (QAxWidget) ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: (1) There are no special signals but Qt ones. (2) Not clear what you asking and what 'it' supposed to be opening.

Comment: When we set any URL on link and click on that link then it is redirecting to that URL with opening new instance of IE. So i do  not want to open IE browser but i want to handle it my own.